# Servo Motor control code issues - Arduino

Tags: arduino

Is there a simple way of modifying the following code so that I can interrupt case '0' with another input. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with millis(), but the examples I've seen seem too complicated. I'm pretty new to coding, so any help will be great! Thanks. :)

```
    #include <Servo.h> 

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo 

void setup() 
{ 
  myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object 
  Serial.begin(9600); //begins serial communication
} 

void loop() 
{ 
  int pos;
  if (Serial.available()){
    delay(100);
    while(Serial.available()>0){
      pos=Serial.read();     //reads the value sent from Visual Basic  
      if(pos=='0'){
   myservo.write(45);  // Turn Servo Left to 45 degrees
   delay(1000);
   // Wait 1 second
   myservo.write(0);   // Turn Servo Left to 0 degrees
   delay(1000);          // Wait 1 second
   myservo.write(90);  // Turn Servo back to center position (90 degrees)
   delay(2000);          // Wait 2 second
   myservo.write(135); // Turn Servo Right to 135 degrees
   delay(1000);          // Wait 1 second
   myservo.write(180); // Turn Servo Right to 180 degrees
   delay(4000);          // Wait 4 second
   myservo.write(90);  // Turn Servo back to center position (90 degrees)
   delay(1000);}          // Wait 1 second
      else if(pos=='1')
        myservo.write(-90);  //rotates the servo 90 degrees (right)
      else if(pos=='2')
        myservo.write(180);  //rotates the servo 180 degrees (Left)
      else if(pos=='3')
        myservo.write(-180); //rotates the servo 180 degrees (right)     
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? I'm reading that you would like to have something other than '0' input from serial run that set of commands. Is that right?

Comment: I am trying to control a servo motor using an Android device. At the moment, I can type into the device either 0, 1, 2 or 3 and each of these will make the motor do something different. However, if I press 0 and then press 2, for example, I have to wait until 0 has finished before anything else can be done. I want the motor to change straight away, rather than having to wait. I hope that's clear, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make two new variables `int servoStep;` & `int timer` outside the loop. Then make a new function for controling the servo and instead of using delay() you can use millis() like this.

```
#include <Servo.h> 

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo 
int servoStep;  // variable to hold witch step is pending
int timer;      // variable to hold time since last step

void setup() 
{ 
  myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object 
  Serial.begin(9600); //begins serial communication
} 

void loop() 
{ 
  int pos;
  if (Serial.available()){
    delay(100);
    while(Serial.available()>0){
      pos=Serial.read();     //reads the value sent from Visual Basic  
      if(pos=='0'){
        servoStep = 1;
      }  
      else if(pos=='1') {
        servoStep = 0;
        myservo.write(-90);  //rotates the servo 90 degrees (right)
      }
      else if(pos=='2') {
        servoStep = 0;
        myservo.write(180);  //rotates the servo 180 degrees (Left)
      }
      else if(pos=='3') {
        servoStep = 0;
        myservo.write(-180); //rotates the servo 180 degrees (right) 
      }    
    }
  }
   if(servoStep != 0) {
    servoControle(servoStep);
   } 
} 
void servoControle(int v) {
  switch (v) {
    case 1:
      timer = millis();
      myservo.write(45);
      servoStep++;
      break;
    case 2:
      if(timer+1000 <= millis()) {
        myservo.write(0);
        servoStep++;
        timer = millis();
      }
      break;
    case 3:
      if(timer+1000 <= millis()) {
        myservo.write(90);
        servoStep++;
        timer = millis();
      }
      break;
    case 4:
      if(timer+2000 <= millis()) {
        myservo.write(135);
        servoStep++;
        timer = millis();
      }
      break;
    case 5:
      if(timer+1000 <= millis()) {
        myservo.write(180);
        servoStep++;
        timer = millis();
      }
      break;
    case 6:
      if(timer+4000 <= millis()) {
        myservo.write(90);
        servoStep = 0;
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Using `millis()` will let the sketch keep running where a delay is needed.
I have not testet it so let me know if it works.

And here is the same code with the servo speed implemented.

```
#include <Servo.h> 

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo 
int servoStep;
int stepActive;
int timer;
int speedTimer;

void setup() 
{ 
  myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object 
  Serial.begin(9600); //begins serial communication
  speedTimer = millis();
} 

void loop() 
{ 
  int pos;
  if (Serial.available()){
    delay(100);
    while(Serial.available()>0){
      pos=Serial.read();     //reads the value sent from Visual Basic  
      if(pos=='0'){
        servoStep = 1;
        Serial.println("0");
      }  
      else if(pos=='1') {
        servoStep = 0;
        myservo.write(-90);  //rotates the servo 90 degrees (right)
        Serial.println("1");
      }
      else if(pos=='2') {
        servoStep = 0;
        myservo.write(180);  //rotates the servo 180 degrees (Left)
        Serial.println("2");
      }
      else if(pos=='3') {
        servoStep = 0;
        myservo.write(-180); //rotates the servo 180 degrees (right) 
        Serial.println("3");
      }    
    }
  }
  if(servoStep != 0) {
    servoControle(servoStep);
  } 
} 
void servoControle(int v) {
  switch (v) {
    case 1:
      if(stepActive == 0) {
        timer = millis();
        stepActive = 1;
      }
      if(speedControle(20, 45) == 1) { // calls the function with these parameters delay=20, new position=45
        servoStep++;                   // and cheks if it is done
        stepActive = 0;
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      if(timer+1000 <= millis()) {
        if(stepActive == 0) {
          timer = millis();
          stepActive = 1;
        }
        if(speedControle(20, 0) == 1) {
        servoStep++;
        stepActive = 0;
        }
      }
      break;
    case 3:
      if(timer+1000 <= millis()) {
        if(stepActive == 0) {
          timer = millis();
          stepActive = 1;
        }
        if(speedControle(20, 90) == 1) {
        servoStep++;
        stepActive = 0;
        }
      }
      break;
    case 4:
      if(timer+2000 <= millis()) {
        if(stepActive == 0) {
          timer = millis();
          stepActive = 1;
        }
        if(speedControle(20, 135) == 1) {
        servoStep++;
        stepActive = 0;
        }
      }
      break;
    case 5:
      if(timer+1000 <= millis()) {
        if(stepActive == 0) {
          timer = millis();
          stepActive = 1;
        }
        if(speedControle(20, 180) == 1) {
        servoStep++;
        stepActive = 0;
        }
      }
      break;
    case 6:
      if(timer+4000 <= millis()) {
        if(stepActive == 0) {
          timer = millis();
          stepActive = 1;
        }
        if(speedControle(20, 90) == 1) {
        servoStep = 0;
        stepActive = 0;
        }
      }
      break;
  }
}
int speedControle(int dly, int pos) {   // function that needs delay and new position
  int currentPos = myservo.read();      // reads last position
  if(speedTimer+dly <= millis()) {      // manages the delay
    if(currentPos > pos) {              // chek if new position is clockwise og not
      myservo.write(currentPos-1);      // moves servo one degree
      speedTimer = millis();            
    } else if(currentPos < pos) {
      myservo.write(currentPos+1);
      speedTimer = millis();
    } else if(currentPos == pos) {      // cheks if function is completed
      return 1;
    }
  }
}
```

If you need help understanding the code your welcome to ask. The idea is for you to learn doing this yourself. ;)

Comment: I've just tested it and it works great, thanks! My next step is to switch LEDs on that slowly dim, for each of the if(pos=='x') statements. So am I right in thinking that this can be easily incorporated into the above code? Cheers.

Comment: Another quick question. How can the speed of the servo motor be controlled without using a delay function? Between each of the servo positions for pos=='0', is it possible to control the speed of the servo motor here?

Comment: For dimming the LEDs i'd do that with a "for" loop using delay(). You would not need to break in to a dim anyway.. Trying to figure out how to adjust the speed without using delay. But using mills() the speed will vary as the sketch getting more complex.

Comment: Chek the new code above. Still not testet. I dont have a spare servo laying around.

Comment: Thanks again, XerXeX!! That code has sorted the speed out. I think from the code you have written I can start to build on it and incorporate LEDs and further servos now.

Comment: I am now trying to add multiple servos to the circuit. So in the code I have added myservo2, myservo3, etc throughout. However, when it comes to the "int speedControle(int dly, int pos)" section, how can i also set this for myservo2, myservo 3, etc? At the moment I am getting an error because I have tried redefining this part of the code. Thanks!

Comment: You might do it by creating the servo object like this: `Servo myservo[1], Servo myservo[2] ...` Then add `int servo` in the speedControle(). An then change the calls to `myservo[servo].read() ... myservo[servo].write`. Then you call the function like this: `speedControle("delay", "angle", "servoNumber")` Hope it works..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm still a bit unsure of the last code part. 'int speedControle(int dly, int pos, int servo) {
  int currentPos = myservo1.read();
  if(speedTimer+dly <= millis()) {
    if(currentPos > pos) {
      myservo1.write(currentPos-1);
      speedTimer = millis();            
    } else if(currentPos < pos) {
      myservo1.write(currentPos+1);
      speedTimer = millis();
    } else if(currentPos == pos) {
      return 1;
    }
  }
}' I started writing this for 'myservo1', but don't know where to put servo2, 3, etc. And it doesn't like me putting 'int servo' in speedControle

Answer (score 0):

The code should look like this:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo[3];  // create servo object to control 3 servos
int servoStep;
int stepActive;
int timer;
int speedTimer;`

void setup() 
{ 
  myservo[0].attach(9);  // attaches servo 1 on pin 9 to the servo object 
  myservo[1].attach(10);  // attaches servo 2 on pin 10 to the servo object 
  myservo[2].attach(11);  // attaches servo 3 on pin 11 to the servo object 
//...ect
  Serial.begin(9600); //begins serial communication
  speedTimer = millis();
} 

void loop() 
{ 
  int pos;
  if (Serial.available()){
    delay(100);
    while(Serial.available()>0){
      pos=Serial.read();     //reads the value sent from Visual Basic  
      if(pos=='0'){
        servoStep = 1;
        Serial.println("0");
      }  
      else if(pos=='1') {
        servoStep = 0;
        myservo[1].write(-90);  //rotates the servo 90 degrees (right)
        Serial.println("1");
      }
      else if(pos=='2') {
        servoStep = 0;
        myservo[1].write(180);  //rotates the servo 180 degrees (Left)
        Serial.println("2");
      }
      else if(pos=='3') {
        servoStep = 0;
        myservo[1].write(-180); //rotates the servo 180 degrees (right) 
        Serial.println("3");
      }    
    }
  }
  if(servoStep != 0) {
    servoControle(servoStep);
  } 
} 
void servoControle(int v) {
  switch (v) {
    case 1:
      if(stepActive == 0) {
        timer = millis();
        stepActive = 1;
      }
      if(speedControle(20, 45, 0) == 1) { // calls the function with these parameters delay=20, new position=45, servo=0(really 1)
        servoStep++;                   // and cheks if it is done
        stepActive = 0;
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      if(timer+1000 <= millis()) {
        if(stepActive == 0) {
          timer = millis();
          stepActive = 1;
        }
        if(speedControle(20, 0, "The servo you want to controle fx. 1") == 1) {
        servoStep++;
        stepActive = 0;
        }
      }
      break;
    case 3:
      if(timer+1000 <= millis()) {
        if(stepActive == 0) {
          timer = millis();
          stepActive = 1;
        }
        if(speedControle(20, 90, "The servo you want to controle fx. 1") == 1) {
        servoStep++;
        stepActive = 0;
        }
      }
      break;
    case 4:
      if(timer+2000 <= millis()) {
        if(stepActive == 0) {
          timer = millis();
          stepActive = 1;
        }
        if(speedControle(20, 135, "The servo you want to controle fx. 1") == 1) {
        servoStep++;
        stepActive = 0;
        }
      }
      break;
    case 5:
      if(timer+1000 <= millis()) {
        if(stepActive == 0) {
          timer = millis();
          stepActive = 1;
        }
        if(speedControle(20, 180, "The servo you want to controle fx. 1") == 1) {
        servoStep++;
        stepActive = 0;
        }
      }
      break;
    case 6:
      if(timer+4000 <= millis()) {
        if(stepActive == 0) {
          timer = millis();
          stepActive = 1;
        }
        if(speedControle(20, 90, "The servo you want to controle fx. 1") == 1) {
        servoStep = 0;
        stepActive = 0;
        }
      }
      break;
  }
}
int speedControle(int dly, int pos, int servo) {   // function that needs delay and new position
  int currentPos = myservo[servo].read();      // reads last position
  if(speedTimer+dly <= millis()) {      // manages the delay
    if(currentPos > pos) {              // chek if new position is clockwise og not
      myservo[servo].write(currentPos-1);      // moves servo one degree
      speedTimer = millis();            
    } else if(currentPos < pos) {
      myservo[servo].write(currentPos+1);
      speedTimer = millis();
    } else if(currentPos == pos) {      // cheks if function is completed
      return 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Haven't testet it..

Comment: Thanks again XerXeX, but now there is a "conflicting declaration" in the code. Not really sure on how to fix this. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Sorry my bad. replace 'Servo myservo[1]; Servo myservo[2];  Servo myservo[3];' with just 'Servo myservo[3];' then remember that servo "1" is in fact "0" so they will be servo[0], servo[1] and servo[2]